Spring Cloud Contract: Escaping Issue with fromRequest() in Response Body
I am using Spring Cloud Contract for testing, and I have a Groovy contract test with the following response body:
message: ["method.page": "The sort fields [${fromRequest().query('sort')}] are not within the allowed values: [sortField]"]
When I use a hardcoded value wrong-sort instead of ${fromRequest().query('sort')}, the generated test has a proper assertion like this:
assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['message']").field("['method.page']")
    .isEqualTo("The sort fields [wrong-sort] are not within the allowed values: [sortField]");

However, when using ${fromRequest().query('sort')}, the generated assertion looks like this:
assertThatJson(parsedJson).field("['message']").field("['method.page']")
    .matches("The sort fields \\\\[wrong-sort\\\\] are not within the allowed values: \\\\[sortField\\\\]");

It appears that unnecessary escaping (\\) is being added to the brackets, which causes the test to fail.
I tried:
message: ["method.page": $("The sort fields [${fromRequest().query('sort')}] are not within the allowed values: [sortField]"]) but the result was the same.
How can I configure the contract to ensure the generated test passes while dynamically including the value of ${fromRequest().query('sort')}?

I resolved this issue using bodyMatchers {}. The problem was with an incorrect jsonPath in my initial attempt. After correcting it, this worked:
response {
    message: [
        "method.page": "The sort fields [${fromRequest().query('sort')}] are not within the allowed values: [sortField]"
    ]
}

bodyMatchers {
    jsonPath('$.message["method.page"]', byRegex('The sort fields \\[.*\\] are not within the allowed values: \\[sortField\\]'))
}

This generated a valid test assertion:
assertThat(parsedJson.read("$.message[\"method.page\"]", String.class))
    .matches("The sort fields \\[.*\\] are not within the allowed values: \\[sortField\\]");

